# How would I go about logging in this scenario?

Tags: future, logging

This is my scenario. I have a trigger on a custom object.
The trigger invokes a future method in a class.
This future method then does a series of callouts using a helper class to update other custom objects in the org.

```
TriggerA --> FutureMethod --> Helper --> ExternalCallouts
```

When the FutureMethod creates a request or receives a response it does this via the Helper class. 
I want to log the raw response of the external callout to a custom object called StoreMyLogs__c

The only inserts / updates I can have are available in the FutureMethod and at that point I have already lost the raw response. It is not possible to do inserts / updates in the Helper class, where the raw response is available.

So I created a static property on the Helper class to accommodate the raw response. This is not working 100% of the times.

So does anyone have any other ideas to log the http response received from the callout?

Comment: Why it is not possible to insert/update in helper  class? You have response there right?

Comment: If you perform a DML Operation in the helper class, the DML operations in the FutureMethod [will fail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Error-You-have-uncommitted-work-pending-Please-commit-or-rollback-before-calling-out&language=en_US&type=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds familiar... You can create a Class who's job it is to collect your StoreMyLogs__c records, and eventually commit them to the database.

You can pass your HttpRequest and HttpResponse along to a *static* list in that Class using a *static* method immediately after your HTTP.send(request) methods in your future/helper/wherever in the execution context.

Then (here's the tricky bit) ***just*** before the return statement in your future Class, call another static method to commit your list of StoreMyLogs__c records...

```
global class CalloutLogs {

  public static list<StoreMyLogs__c> logEntries {get;set;} //need a static variable to avoid the pending work exception
  static{
    logEntries = new list<StoreMyLogs__c>();              //We want to make sure that we have an instance of the static var
  }

  public static StoreMyLogs__c log(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response){
    //Converts HttpRequest and HttpResponse to string representations
    //Creates a StoreMyLogs__c record, and adds it to the static list<StoreMyLogs__c> member
    //Returns the StoreMyLogs__c record that was converted
    StoreMyLogs__c returnLog = new StoreMyLogs__c ();
    //marshal your request and response into your StoreMyLogs__c
    //...
    logEntries.add(returnLog);
    return returnLog;
  }

  public static string commitLogs(){
    string returnString = 'Failed to commit StoreMyLogs__c ...';
    if(logEntries != null){
      if(logEntries.size() == 0){
        returnString = 'No StoreMyLogs__c to commit...';
      } else {
        insert logEntries;
        returnString = 'Committed ' + logEntries.size() + ' StoreMyLogs__c  Entries';
      }
    }
    return returnString;
  }
}
```

THEN: just before you return from your future method... call the `commitLogs()` method.

```
system.debug(CalloutLogs.commitLogs());
return; //like the absolute final return!
```

You just need to make sure that you commit only after ALL callouts have been made to avoid the dreaded "pending work" exception.

Comment: I am going to give this a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I did attempt this, but I am back to ``You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out``

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I had to tweak a bit of code on my end to get this going. Thanks once again.